# ocra uninitialized constant CommonElement (NameError)

Tags: ruby, ocra

```
require 'selenium-webdriver'
require 'page-object'

class SubjectSearchPage  < CommonElement
  include PageObject

  text_field(:ssnField, :id => "SSN")
  button(:searchBtn, :css => 'button[data-test-id="20180820140732083632904"]')
  h2(:resultsHeaderTitle, :css => 'div[data-test-id="201808231334560745670_header"] h2.header-title')
  elements(:resultRows, :css => '#bodyTbl_right > tbody > tr')
  span(:result, :css => 'span[data-test-id="2016072109335505834280"]')

end
```

```
require 'selenium-webdriver'
require 'page-object'

class CommonElement
  include PageObject

  h2(:headerTitle, :css => 'h2')
  element(:caseAppLabel, :css => '.content-item.content-label.item-2.remove-top-spacing.remove-bottom-spacing.flex.flex-row.application_name_dataLabelWrite.flex-grow.dataLabelWrite.application_name_dataLabelWrite')
  link(:casesLeftMenu, :css => '.menu-item-anchor.menu-item-expand')
  link(:page_title, :css => '.Application_name')
  link(:footer_nav, :css => '.Footer_nav')
  link(:orgPageTitle, :css => '.content-item.content-label.item-2.flex.flex-row.heading_1_dataLabelWrite.dataLabelWrite.heading_1_dataLabelWrite')

  link(:searchField, :css => '#pySearchText')
  #Left Nav

  link(:manageSubjectsLink, :css => "li[title='Manage Subjects'] a")
  link(:manageOrgLink, :css => "li[title='Manage Org'] a") #dev version
  # link(:settingsLink, :css => "li[title='Settings'] a")
  link(:configMgmtLink, :css => "li[title='Config Management'] a")
  link(:systemSettingsLink, :css => "li[title='System Settings'] a")

  #Modal

  span(:modalTitle, :id =>"modaldialog_hd_title")
end
```

I have displayed both classes when try to convert using OCRA its throwing error. Any help ?

> ```
> c:/Users/seshaddri/git/pega-functional-tests/selenium-ruby/pages/subject_mgmt/subject_search_page.rb:4:in `<top (required)>': uninitialized constant CommonElement (NameError)
>         from C:/Bitnami/rubystack-2.3.8-1/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/ocra-1.3.10/bin/ocra:1211:in `load'
>         from C:/Bitnami/rubystack-2.3.8-1/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/ocra-1.3.10/bin/ocra:1211:in `<top (required)>'
>         from C:/Bitnami/rubystack-2.3.8-1/ruby/bin/ocra:23:in `load'
>         from C:/Bitnami/rubystack-2.3.8-1/ruby/bin/ocra:23:in `<main>'
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you're getting says it all:

> uninitialized constant CommonElement (NameError)

This means that `CommonElement` is not defined yet. Try requiring it before defining the inheritance:

```
require 'selenium-webdriver'
require 'page-object'

require_relative 'common_element'
# ^ new assuming CommonElement is present in ./common_element.rb

class SubjectSearchPage < CommonElement
```

Comment: Its local library part of common module. I have enclosed code snippet for your reference in the initial post.

Comment: I've updated the answer answer. I guess you aren't using bundler. And your project directory isn't added to `$LOAD_PATH`.

Comment: Thanks it worked, what command should be used if the file in not same folder.

Comment: Just provide the relative path. Examples could be: `require_relative 'some_folder/another_folder/common_element'` or `require_relative '../another_project/common_element'` (`..` goes up one directory). If the file path is not relative but absolute`require 'c:/full/path/to/file'` should work.

Comment: Alternatively you could consider packaging the common elements as an gem. After installation you can simply `require 'common_element'` since gems should be added to the `$LOAD_PATH`.